# CMake transitive dependency linked by name only

Tags: c++, xcode, cmake, linker, clang

It seems that dylibs linked directly in `target_link_libraries` get linked by absolute path, but those coming in transitively through CMake target dependencies are dropping the absolute path and linking by name only.  This breaks the MacOS fixup bundle functionality that normally post-processes an `.app` directory to include the libraries in relocatable fashion because it can't find the dylib(s).

For example, I have a dependency on DCMTK, which itself has a dependency on libicu.  DCMTK is built by for static linking by CMake, so it has a targets config file and it lists the dependency on the libicu dylib by absolute path:

```
$ grep libicu DCMTKTargets-release.cmake
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES_RELEASE "/usr/local/app-libs/icu-67.1/lib/libicuuc.dylib;/usr/local/app-libs/icu-67.1/lib/libicudata.dylib;pthread"
```

Here is a minimal CMake to reproduce, although you of course need to build `libicu` for dynamic linking and `DCMTK` for static linking in the paths shown.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(CatalinaTest)

set(CMAKE_OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET "10.14" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_OSX_SYSROOT})


list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
  /usr/local/app-libs/vscdcmtk-3.6.3/lib/cmake/dcmtk
)

find_package(LibXml2 REQUIRED)
find_package(DCMTK REQUIRED CONFIG)

add_executable(CatalinaTest main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(CatalinaTest
  ${LIBXML2_LIBRARIES}
  ofstd
)
```

The linker command that runs is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -target x86_64-apple-macos10.14 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk -L/Users/jake/devel/cmake-test.build/Release -F/Users/jake/devel/cmake-test.build/Release -filelist /Users/jake/devel/cmake-test.build/CatalinaTest.build/Release/CatalinaTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CatalinaTest.LinkFileList -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libxml2.tbd /usr/local/app-libs/vscdcmtk-3.6.3/lib/libofstd.a /usr/local/app-libs/icu-67.1/lib/libicuuc.dylib /usr/local/app-libs/icu-67.1/lib/libicudata.dylib -lpthread -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/jake/devel/cmake-test.build/CatalinaTest.build/Release/CatalinaTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CatalinaTest_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/jake/devel/cmake-test.build/Release/CatalinaTest
```

So it passes both direct and transitive dependencies by absolute path in the same section without any other linker modification flags between.  Now, in the linked executable:

```
$ otool -L Release/CatalinaTest 
Release/CatalinaTest:
    /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.9.0)
    libicuuc.67.dylib (compatibility version 67.0.0, current version 67.1.0)
    libicudata.67.dylib (compatibility version 67.0.0, current version 67.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1281.100.1)
    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 902.1.0)
```

We can see `libxml2`'s dylib has the absolute path but `libicu`'s two dylibs do not.  Although this example has a `tbd` file for `libxml2`, the behavior is the same if we use another library that passes a `dylib` directly.  The difference seems to be all indirect/transitive dylibs are name-only, and all direct dylibs get the absolute path.

What is causing this difference and how can I get the transitive dylibs to link by full path so that bundle post processing can proceed as expected?

Comment: can you try using "otool -l" instead and see if you have RPATH entries ? did you "make install" since path can be rewritten ? or did you use  `set(CMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH TRUE)` ? you can also try to play with  `set_target_properties(target PROPERTIES
    INSTALL_RPATH "@loader_path"` to get some relative path

Comment: No rpath entries in the executable.  You can see my test CMakeLists.txt above, no rpath directives there.  I did not use the `install` target, I ran otool on the executable in the build directory.  `otool -l` doesn't show anything more than `otool -L`: https://pastebin.com/bRHfjvUH